# Issue in Connection String C# and Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 using C# in Visual 2010. I am having an issue in that

![enter image description here][1]

Can anyone identify that issue and help me regarding that issue?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;"+"Intial Catalog=company; Integrated Security=SSPI";
try
{
    con.open();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Messagebox.show("exception is thrown for db connection");
}
```

Comment: does it compile? What exception is thrown?

Comment: Your issue description isn't clear.

Comment: If you actually display the exception details you'll get the clues you need. In other words, put a break point in the catch block and examine the contents of the `e` variable.

Comment: why there is  a `;"+"` in the connection string?

Comment: For the sake of humanity. Be sure to either use the `using` keyword or to properly close and dispose of your connection object. It is possible you're starving the connection pool and that's causing your issues as is.

Comment: @Hiten004: ;"+" is probably because he had it split over lines, shouldnt matter tho... 
- have you already checked if your firewall has its ports for sqlserver opened? 
- does your database require authentication? do you provide credentials if it does?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information we have no way to tell you what is wrong directly, but can give an indirect answer to provide information to go about finding out what is wrong. That advice would be not to swallow your exception.

That is, you catch something as it goes wrong, yet ignore the parameter value of the thing that would tell you why it went wrong, `e`. Instead of a generic message, in this instance, use that thing:

```
 Messagebox.show(e.Message);
```